# Solving for values of a Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be an integrable function on $\bf R$. Given constants $A,B>0$, does there always exist an $x$ satisfying the following equation?
$$A=Bx+\hat{f}(x)=Bx+\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(t)e^{ixt}dt$$
Perhaps one may need to impose further conditions on $f(x)$ for this to be true?

Comment: If one introduces [Generalized Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), then by inverting the equation, one finds that $$f(t)=A\delta(t)+iB\delta'(t)$$where $\delta$ is the [Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and $\delta'$ is the [Dirac Unit Doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_doublet).  Obviously, $f$ is not integrable in the sense of Riemann or Lebesgue, but rather a distribution.

Answer (score 1):

$\hat f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\hat f(x)=0$. Then $B\,x+\hat f(x)$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\hat f(x)=\pm\infty$. The mean value theorem shows that the equation $B\,x+\hat f(x)=A$ has at least one solution.